# Make style item like journal

Tags: css

i want to make style css like journal style

**example**
http://themes.pixelb.in/journal/

i try to make this

**html**

```
<header><!-- ... --></header>
<div id="content">
<div class="item">
here is item con
</div>
<div class="item">
here is item con
</div>
<div class="item">
here is item con
</div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
#content {
  width: 90%;
}
.item {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co). This will arrange the items for you in an easy way using Jquery.